# Websphere security role to user mapping issue

Tags: java, active-directory, websphere

I have my websphere application server integrated with AD, I have added a AD user to the application deloyed on Websphere using security role to user mapping, but it is not being reflected in the application. The same works in other environments. The issue is in my local setup.

Please if any one can suggest me the reason for this. ]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have my websphere application server integrated with AD, I have added a AD user to the application deployed on Websphere 

For Ex: Websphere Enterprise Applications —> Application(directory EAR) —> Security role to user/group mapping —> Map Users —> Click Save

Even after granting the required roles, the application is not reflected with these roles, whereas in other environments like Dev, QA and Prod this works fine.

The issue is in my local setup. Any other changes are needed at Websphere side for this particular functionality to be working in local IDE setup.